# How to center table and move header and footer with `tabularray` and `pdflscape`?

Tags: tabularray, pdflscape

I know centring table with `\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}` and how to delete header and footer with `\thispagestyle{empty}`. But in `tabularray` and `pdflscape` environments, it seems not centered and can't be no header and foot. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}    
\section{New section}
\lipsum{1-6}
    \begin{landscape}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-3cm}
        \begin{longtblr}[caption={hello},
        label={tab:table1}]{
        colspec={*{17}{X[c]}}
        }
        \SetCell[c=2]{m} 1& &{{{3\\3\\4}}}&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{landscape}
\lipsum{1-6}
\end{document}
```

The result is as:

[image]

Another three questions:

1. Why `\SetCell[c=2]{m} 1` didn't make `1` in the middle?
2. How to fill the blank with text between the portrait and landscape paper?
3. If I use `TblrNote` to insert many notes in this table. All the notes will be shown at the bottom of the table. Is there a way to make every note shown in the page where its symbol shown?

Answer (score 2):

- **how to delete header and footer with `\thispagestyle{empty}`**?

`thispagestyle{empty}` only changes the header for one page. As your table has more than one page you should use `\pagestyle{empty}` instead. As you do this inside the `landscape` environment, and `\pagestyle` is a local declaration, after the `landscape` environment is finished the pagestyle will be automatically reset to its previous value. As the `landscape` environment starts and ends with a page break, the changes of the page style work correctly.

- Why `\SetCell[c=2]{m} 1` didn't make `1` in the middle?

This is a misconception of what `m` means. It doesn't mean put the contents vertically centered in the cell. Instead it means: put the baseline of the contents in the vertical center of this contents. In a row all the baselines of the cells are put at the same level. All the other cells in the row have their baselines at the to (or only line), so that is where the vertical center of the first cell comes. If you would use  `\SetCell[c=1]{m}` for the second cell `{3\\3\\4}`, then the first cell would be aligned with the center of the second cell, but also all the others in the row. If you want that then that is the solution. If not, The you could add an empty line on top of the first cell, like:

`\SetCell[c=2]{t} {\mbox{}\\1}`

- How to fill the blank with text between the portrait and landscape paper?

The `landscape` environment starts a new page, so if you want to fill up the page first you have to delay this until there is a page break. This can be done with the `afterpage` package. If your LaTeX installation is new enough you can use for example an `shipout/after` hook, but I'll use afterpage here, just in case.

As it is adviced to use only small amounts of code in `\afterpage`, I am going to put the table in a separate file. So put the code starting at `\begin{landscape}` and ending at `\end{landscape}` (including both), in a sperate file `lscapetable.tex`. and in the main file, where it used to be, replace it by

`\afterpage{\input{lscapetable}}`, and put `\usepackage{afterpage}` in the preamble.

- If I use `TblrNote` to insert many notes in this table. All the notes will be shown at the bottom of the table. Is there a way to make every note shown in the page where its symbol shown?

I have no idea.

Here is my complete solution (by the way, `\lipsum` uses `[...]` for its argument):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}    
\section{New section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\afterpage{\input{lscapetable}}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

file `lscapetable.tex`

```
    \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
        \begin{longtblr}[caption={hello},
        label={tab:table1}]{
        colspec={*{17}{X[c]}}
        }
        \SetCell[c=2]{t} {\mbox{}\\1} & &{{{3\\3\\4}}}&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{landscape}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. But how to centre the table on those pages?

Comment: Another question, is how to justify the content in table cells as I use `SetCell{j}` can't do that.

Comment: Centering the tables: I would suggest to adapt the parameters of `\begin{adjustwidth}` until the table is centered. How much that would be depends on the paper size.

Comment: I tested that using `adjustwidth` can't canter that table. And how to justify the content in table cells?

Comment: Center in  which direction?

Comment: Justifying works with `j`, but only in cells/columns with a specified width. The width can be implied by having an `X` column, or by using `wd=<width>`.

Comment: In my picture, the table was not centered in the page at horizontal direction, or at horizontal and vertical directions at the same. I hope some text such as "Hello" of a cell is justified in the cell. To do that, I use `\SetCell{j} Hello`, but it is aligned left not justified.

Comment: You cannot justify a one word text. Justifying applies to a paragraph of more than one line. (actually you will only notice it if there are more than two lines).

Comment: I could more or less center your table in horizontal direction with `\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{-2cm}` on A4 paper. I would probably need some more mm fine tuning. With other paper sizes this would be different. For centering vertically on the rotated page, you would probably need the `\changepage` command from the `changepage` package (not the outdated `chngpage`). It might be tricky with the rotated pages, because `lscape` on which `pdflscape` is based, modifies some aspects of the page layout but not all of them. So I am not sure if the `\changepage` command will work correctly here.

Comment: Is there a way to justify one word text?  How to align the table center? I test three line words but they are not justified by `\SetCell{j} Hello`.

Comment: What does justifying a one word text mean?

Comment: For example, in one cell there is a word `hello`, and I want to make this word as wide as the cell width: `h e l l o`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136677/discussion-between-pieter-van-oostrum-and-y-zeng).